# php Adding numbers in a variable and a string

Tags: php

I want to be able to add a number from a variable and from a string together. The variable `$userinfo->pilotid` will always be different depending on a User ID, for example it maybe `1`.

I'd like to introduce an offset to this variable, by always adding `1000` to that number. How can I add the both with this?

```
Auth::$userinfo->code . '' . Auth::$userinfo->pilotid
```

Something along the lines of...

```
$offset = '1000';
echo Auth::$userinfo->code . '' . Auth::$userinfo->pilotid + $offset
```

Would the above work or am I mixing up things?

Comment: yes why not use correct concatenation that's all

Comment: It echoes `10001000`. `$userinfo->pilotid` when printed is 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use parenthesis so that you add the offset rather than concatenating the offset:

```
echo Auth::$userinfo->code . '' . (Auth::$userinfo->pilotid + $offset);
```

Answer (score 0):

When concatenating, you don't need to include the `''`, and you should wrap the addition operation in parenthesis.

```
$offset = 1000;
echo Auth::$userinfo->code . (Auth::$userinfo->pilotid + $offset);
```

The `''` was superfluous as it added nothing. PHP has [`type juggling`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), so you can concatenate an integer directly onto a string. You just need to perform the addition separately, ergo the parenthesis.